# How to push lineprotocol data into influxdb in golang?

Tags: go, influxdb

I have JSON data coming from Prometheus metric and I have converted it into line-protocol.

How can I push this converted data into influx db using golang?

Comment: What have you tried so far? What problems did you run into?

Comment: I have used http.NewRequest("GET",prometheous-metric url) to get json data. then have used "github.com/gernest/blue" package  to convert into lineprotocol. sorry i m new to influxdb and struck with sending this data to influx

Answer (score 2):

I did not find answer for this anywhere else. I am using influxdb 1.7.10 and for that I posted data using HttpRequest

```
var ServerAddress = "http://localhost:8086/write?db=mydb&u=username&p=password"
func PostData(data string) {
    d := bytes.NewReader([]byte(data))
    req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", ServerAddress, d)
    if err != nil {
        print(err)
    }

    client := &http.Client{}
    resp, err := client.Do(req)

    defer resp.Body.Close()
    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    if err != nil {
        print(err)
    }

    fmt.Print(string(body))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [InfluxDB golang Client](https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb/tree/master/client)

I assume the structure would something like

```
 inputMeas := "meas1,tag1=va1,tag2=va2 value=342"
 client.Write(inputMeas)
 // check for response status
```

The Above mentioned client infact has a detailed `README` in order to better understand how you can write your information to InfluxDB. If you have a lot of information you can try using Batch Upload also.